# HTML - PDF Text render issues (DOMPDF Jumbles Texts after 7-10 html lines)

Tags: php, html, web, dompdf

The images show the differences between what I get on my XAMPP and my Real Server.

My XAMPP is fine whereas the production server is having issues.

I'm using the DOMPDF library. Please take a look and help with possible fixes.

Going into the details of the code is quite unnecessary cos it works fine on one. I just need possible errors and fixes.

The munch of what I'm getting from the public server:

[image: The munch of what I'm getting from the public server]

The munch of what I get from my XAMPP:

[image: The munch of what I get from my XAMPP]

Thank you.

Comment: start by comparing php and library versions

Comment: I simply ftp'ed the library on my XAMPP to the real server.. PHP 5.6.8 on my XAMPP and 5.6.23 on my Real Server

Comment: Can you show us your HTML?

Comment: doubt it's a php version. it's dompdf that does the actual work. compare versions there.

Comment: @Marc B... I simply FTP'ed the DOMPDF library to my real server. So I expected same result.

Comment: and what about whatever dompdf uses internally? perhaps it calls on ghostscript or something. you have to check everything, not just php versions.

Comment: @Marc B .. My concern is that even if it runs ghostscripts, it renders well on on my XAMPP server... This same ghostscripts ought to perform the same function on my real server. I'm lost and confused.

Comment: Are you uploading directly from XAMPP to your server? If so there's a good chance the font file references are now invalid. When this happens the font metrics can't be found, resulting in invalid text rendering. The quickest way to check that out is to reset your font directory and font cache directory back to the default.

Comment: @BrianS  Oops! Done lots of look up on how I could reset the font cache directory. No luck. However it is safe to note that I FTP with Fz not XAMMP.

Comment: @BrianS Thanks for the hint on fonts. Well I fixed it by editing the dompdf_font_family_cache.php file. It renders properly now.

Answer (score 1):

Dompdf caches font information in dompdf/lib/fonts/dompdf_font_family_cache.php (in order versions the extension was excluded). This file contains path information for the font files loaded into dompdf. Some versions of Dompdf will write the file path information such that copying Dompdf from one system to another is possible. Other versions, however, do not.

For those versions that do not create generalized font file paths the information in the font cache will be invalid. Because of the invalid paths Dompdf will not be able to find the font metrics files. Dompdf will still attempt to render the fonts since it believe they are installed, but the resulting text placement will be incorrect.

The quickest way to confirm this is the problem is to reset your font directory and font cache directory back to the default. Specifically, try removing or renaming the dompdf_font_family_cache.php file.

(Based on comments to the question.)